# correctly downloaded node.js but still unable to install browser-sync and getting these warnings

Tags: node.js, browser-sync

The warning message is as follows :

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ browser-sync@2.26.10
updated 1 package in 17.438s
```

Comment: That message is telling you browser-sync did install. The warnings are just that: warnings. They do not mean the update failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a message telling you that `fsevents` wasn't installed because it's an optional package, but `browser-events` was installed.

---

The first line is:

```
SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents
```

This means that for some reason or another, `fsevents` wasn't installed.

If you then go to the second line, it tells you why:

```
Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

If we look on the [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) of `fsevents`:

> Native access to MacOS FSEvents in Node.js

We can see that `fsevents` is a package ment to be used for MacOS. OS `darwin` is the equivalent to MacOS. Since you have Windows installed, node didn't install `fsevents`

The next line:

```
+ browser-sync@2.26.10
```

This shows that it added (`+`) `browser-sync` version 2.26.10 `@2.26.10`.

Then the last line is a summary that simply shows what node did.

Comment: ok, but after that whenever i check its version in cmd it shows something like this error :YError: Invalid first argument. Expected boolean or string but received function.
    at argumentTypeError (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\argsert.js:64:11)

Comment: i was checking its version by using command browser-sync --version. @ent3r_